# React Jodit toolbar appears in multiple lines

Tags: reactjs, jodit

I am try to experiment with react jodit. I copy the example code but it shows the toolbar in multiple line. My code is as below

```
<div className="mx-auto sm:max-w-screen lg:max-w-7xl">
        <JoditEditor
          value={this.content}
          tabIndex={1}
          onChange={value => this.content = value}
        />
      </div>
```

Please help
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Issue root caused. I just found out there is a conflict in another css where it configure `div` class to 100% width . So it cause the `jodit-ui-separator` class to be a new line.